# SSIS error "cannot detach from one or more processes"

Tags: ssis

i have a package which runs for about 6 hours. I looked at it every once in a while, it was going well. In the morning i saw that every task was green and it said "Execution completed", but when i clicked on it to stop the process, i got this message - "cannot detach from one or more processes. Would you like to terminate them instead?" So i chose yes. 
The question is is it safe to continue with my work? Did the termination affect my DB somehow? 
Again, all the tasks where already completed.
Will appreciate a quick response as i don't know whether to proceed or execute the package again..
thank you! 
I'm using SQL Server 2005 and visual studio 2005

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with the designerm, not with the package itself, so I would say you can deatach

Quick question, are you using checkpoints on a package that big?
If not, I suggest you to use it. If you dont know what it is, its basically a functionality to allow your package to run from the point of failure. So, if you pacakge fails at 5:30, you can rerun it from the last checkpoint taking just an hour opposed as runnig everything again

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the checkpoint suggestion. I find them cool in concept but deplorable in implementation. They do not preserve the value of complex variables, the state of loops nor do events refire when a package is restarted from them. Instead, my advice is to design packages so they can gracefully recover from failures (sane transaction scoping, queries to inspect how much work remains, has this task already been done, etc)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I don't want to add anything to the package because it wasn't built by me and it's super complicated, so as long as it works i prefer not to touch it:)

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem, I have increased the buffer size from 10000 to 100000 that resolved the issue. Please try this.